# Why `libsvm` in matlab gives me all 1 prediction

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I use `svm` in `R`and `matlab` with the same [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1na248936ofd5h/data.mat?dl=0).

My R code works fine, which gives me some reasonable predictions.

```
matdat <- readMat(con = "data.mat")
svm.model <- svm(x = matdat$normalize.X, y = matdat$Yt)
pred <- predict(svm.model, newdata = matdat$normalize.X)
pred <- sapply(pred, function(x){ifelse(x > 0, 1, -1)})
sum(pred == matdat$Yt)/length(matdat$Yt)
```

But, my matlab code gives me all 1 prediction on the training data.

```
load('data.mat')
model2 = svmtrain(Yt, normalize_X,'-s 3 -c 1 -t 2 -p 0.1');
[predicted_label,accuracy, decision_values] = svmpredict(Yt, normalize_X, model2);
```

I have checked the default parameters of `svm{e1071}`, which in my opinion agrees with the matlab version.

I use the `e1071` package with verion 1.6-7 in R. And the latest `libsvm` from the official page.

So, what can I do to find the reason, any ideas?

==== update====

Before feeding the data to libsvm in data, I apply `mapstd` to normalize the data which is automatically done in R. Then I got the same trained model in both R and Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab you use the `-s 3` option which is regression, not classification.
As a starting point, don't assume anything about default parameters, just specify parameters explicitly in both R and Matlab.